# How to do the protected route in nextjs

Tags: typescript, routes, next.js, redux-toolkit

here I created an HOC for protected route in Nextjs and imported in app.tsx file but the path is going well and my doubt is when I submit with valid credentials it not going into dashboard it is reflecting into the login page only

I need to move into the dashboard